# how to update firebase realtime database data with child_changed

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crud

I am attempting to update data in my firebase realtime db and I want to listen to my child changed event so I can see it update in realtime. I am getting an error on my set function as my error is "previousSchools.set() is not a function". I also tried using setState since I am manipulating data thats already in my DB. I am very new to firebase and react,  but I thought I could do something similar to my child_added function, but tweak it a bit. I was also not really able to find many examples of people using child_changed. My current code is:

```
        this.database.on('child_changed', snap => {
                    previousSchools.set({
                        id: snap.key,
                        schoolName: snap.val().schoolName,
                        dateStarted: snap.val().dateStarted,
                        totalVolunteerHours: parseInt(snap.val().totalVolunteerHours),
                        totalLobbyHours: parseInt(snap.val().totalLobbyHours),
                    })
                
                    this.setState({
                        schools: previousSchools
                    })
        })
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `previousSchools`? Please make sure its initialization is included in the code you share. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it contains much more great guidance to maximize the chance someone can help you.

Comment: Thanks, previous schools is an array that I assign to the current state of my schools array at the beginning of my componentDidMount() function. I appreciate the links, I was unsure on whether I should include more code or if it would just become overhwelming.

Comment: Don't include or describe the code in a comment please, but edit your question to include it. If you think the code may be overwhelming, read the link again: it recommend starting from scratch, and reproducing the problem in isolation. If you do that, you'll be surprised how small you can often make it (and how disconnected from your domain).